# recovering associations within associations when using papertrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many, paper-trail-gem

in paper_trail one of the caveats is that only the first level of associations is recovered, this is a problem if you have associations within associations

If I have...

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
end

class Attendances < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  has_many :point_logs, dependent: :destroy
end

class PointLogs < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

If I deleted a student I would `student.versions.last.reify(:has_many => true)` to recover the deleted attendances and student and then separately `pointlog.version.last.reify` to recover the deleted pointlog

Is this the best way for recovering nested cascade deletes, or is there a better way to address this caveat within paper_trail?

Answer (score 0):

So here is a possible solution that takes it a bit further. I had a similar issue, but wanted to it not be so explicit as it must work for multiple models.  Here is a module I created, that I include in the top level of the chain of versions, so in your case, I would include this in Student.

```
  # This method finds the current reified model's has_many relationships and
  # recursively reifies has_many relationships until the end
  #
  # @param [ActiveRecord::Base] model_version is a reified active_record model
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Base] model_version
  def self.reify_has_many_associations(model_version)
    associations = model_version.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).select { |a| a.klass.paper_trail.enabled? }.map(&:name)
    if associations.present?
      associations.each do |a|
        models = model_version.method(a).call
        models.each do |m|
          if m.version
            m.version.reify(has_many: true)
            ::Revertable.reify_has_many_associations(m)
          end
        end
      end
    end
    model_version
  end
```